# Is there a setting to prevent jaggy sides?

Tags: webgl

I searched about these jaggy sides and learned that multisampling and antialiasing is enabled in WebGL by default but it still seems too jaggy for me. Is there another setting which makes sides look smoother than this?

[image: jaggy cube]

[image: from far]

Also can you tell me is this picture normal? I am looking more far away than 1st one. This is MUCH more jaggy.

I am working on rendering to a texture. In the jaggy example, I was rendering to a texture of 512*512 but my canvas vas 400*300. When I changed my canvas to 512*512 as in texture to be rendered to, jagginess disappeared. Sides become much more smooth. When I set the texture size to 1024*1024 it became much more better. It seems that, texture size should be same as canvas size and both must be power of two because when I set both to 400*300, cube became jaggy. I do not know the reason though. Texture can not be sampled properly if sizes do not match I suppose.

Comment: No. If You need a quick solution: set in CSS w & h and double the resolution of the canvas (width & height). Other techniques require deep knowledge and the fine art of WebGL programming. BTW, enabling `antialias` is just a *hint* for the browser to use it when possible/available.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what I was working on. I posted details below.